# i3: change focus_follows_mouse with keybinding

Tags: i3

As we know, the window manager i3 provides an option to control the behavior of the mouse moving from one window to another - the `focus_follows_mouse` option.

I wanted to control this behavior with my keyboard, so I tried to add this in my config:

```
bindsym $mod+b focus_follows_mouse yes
```

It doesn't do anything. I tried:

```
bindsym $mod+n exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'focus_follows_mouse no'
```

Same result.

Is there a possibility to change the value for focus_follows_mouse without changing the config everytime?

I'm using version 4.15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

Since this command is not part of the user guide section [List of Commands](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#list_of_commands). It is not one of the commands accepted by `i3-msg`.
This would be the only way to toggle this with a keybinding and without reloading a different configuration file.

Answer (score 3):

Even though it's four years late and you've probably moved on, I'm answering this for anyone that comes across this when searching for a solution to this, like me.

There are still no easy, official ways to do this. But it is possible with a sed and i3-msg reload:

```
bindsym $mod+n exec --no-startup-id "sed -i '/^focus_follows_mouse/{s/yes/no/;t;s/no/yes/}' ~/.config/i3/config; i3-msg reload"
```

Replace the `$mod+n` with your preferred keybind, and as long as you have a line of `focus_follows_mouse yes` or `focus_follows_mouse no` in your i3 config, this should work.

Comment: Great answer! I was thinking about changing my accepted answer, but I asked ` without changing the config everytime`, so IMO "It is not possible" is still the right answer (also I have moved on...)